# After providing username and password when running git clone, \n is being embedded

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm providing username and password while doing a git clone operation like this git clone  https://user:password@repourl but its failing to clone and I see \n is being embedded into url so how can I overcome this error ?
Error - https://user:password\n@repourl"

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a credential helper which might interfere in your case:

```
git config credential.helper
```

If not, depending on your OS, try to use one, and do not specify the password

```
git config credential.helper manager (for example, if you are on Windows)
git clone https://user@repourl
```

Remember, if you have [2FA activated on BitBucket](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/enable-two-step-verification/), you will need an [app password](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/) instead of your BitBucket account regular password.